# How to insert background image on sprite class in libGDX?

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite

I'm new to this framework libGDX i used this for my top down game . I've already search but my code does't work.How can I insert background image in sprite class or how can i import the sprite class in another activity? 
here is my code. Thank's and advance :)

Sprite.java

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

public class Sprite implements ApplicationListener {
    // Constant rows and columns of the sprite sheet
    private static final int FRAME_COLS = 5, FRAME_ROWS = 1;

    // Objects used
    Animation<TextureRegion> walkAnimation; // Must declare frame type (TextureRegion)
    Texture walkSheet;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    // A variable for tracking elapsed time for the animation
    float stateTime;

@Override
public void create() {

    // Load the sprite sheet as a
    walkSheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cat2.png"));
    // Use the split utility method to create a 2D array of TextureRegions. This is
    // possible because this sprite sheet contains frames of equal size and they are
    // all aligned.
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheet,
            walkSheet.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS,
            walkSheet.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS);

    // Place the regions into a 1D array in the correct order, starting from the top
    // left, going across first. The Animation constructor requires a 1D array.

    TextureRegion[] walkFrames = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
        }
    }
    // Initialize the Animation with the frame interval and array of frames
    walkAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.075f, walkFrames);

    // Instantiate a SpriteBatch for drawing and reset the elapsed animation
    // time to 0
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    stateTime = 0f;
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear screen
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // Accumulate elapsed animation time

    // Get current frame of animation for the current stateTime
    TextureRegion currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame, 50, 50); // Draw current frame at (50, 50)
    spriteBatch.end();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() { // SpriteBatches and Textures must always be disposed
    spriteBatch.dispose();
    walkSheet.dispose();
  }
}
```

Gameview.java

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;

public class Gameview extends Game {

private Stage stage;
private Texture myTexture;
private TextureRegion myTextureRegion;
private TextureRegionDrawable myTexRegionDrawable;
private ImageButton button;

@Override
public void create()
{
    myTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("floor.png"));
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(myTexture);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    button = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up

    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport()); //Set up a stage for the ui
    stage.addActor(button); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); //Start taking input from the ui
}

@Override
public void render()
{
    //Clear the screen, set the clear color, yada, yada
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()); //Perform ui logic
    stage.draw(); //Draw the ui
}
}
```

Comment: Sprite is predefined class in Libgdx why don't use another name.

Comment: can you give me sir @AbhishekAryan a sample or tutorial? I have 2 class the one is the game view and sprite class..how can i  render the sprite class in my game view class?

Comment: why your Sprite class implement ApplicationListener ?

Comment: choose any one **Game/ ApplicationAdapter/ApplicationListener** in your game

Comment: I just follow the tutorial  here they used ApplicationListener (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation)

Comment: I choose ApplicationAdapter..how can i create a background image? or how can put my sprite class in my game view class.? thank you sir for your fast reply.

Comment: I think you want to draw or use Animation in your game. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes sir you are correct.My sprite class is working but the background color is black how can i change that to image?

Comment: Choosing the name Sprite for your class is super confusing and makes your question almost incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Your Sprite class is just a referenced tutorial for Animation. If you want to Play Animation that can use with stage, you're using Stage in GameView class. So delete your Sprite class. Keep only GameView class that extends Game class. In create method create a object of AnimationActor and add to stage.

```
public class AnimationActor extends Actor {

    Texture walkSheet;
    float stateTime;
    private static final int FRAME_COLS = 5, FRAME_ROWS = 1;
    Animation<TextureRegion> walkAnimation;
    TextureRegion reg;

    public AnimationActor() {

        // Load the sprite sheet as a
        walkSheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cat2.png"));
        // Use the split utility method to create a 2D array of TextureRegions. This is
        // possible because this sprite sheet contains frames of equal size and they are
        // all aligned.
        TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheet,
                walkSheet.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS,
                walkSheet.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS);

        // Place the regions into a 1D array in the correct order, starting from the top
        // left, going across first. The Animation constructor requires a 1D array.

        TextureRegion[] walkFrames = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
                walkFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
            }
        }
        // Initialize the Animation with the frame interval and array of frames
        walkAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.075f, walkFrames);
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);

        stateTime += delta;
        reg = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
        if (walkAnimation.getPlayMode() == Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL && walkAnimation.isAnimationFinished(stateTime))
            end();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

        Color color = getColor();
        batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);
        batch.draw(reg, getX(), getY(), getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getRotation());
    }

    public void setPosition(Position origin) {
        this.setPosition(getOriginX() - getWidth() / 2f, getOriginY() - getHeight() / 2f);
    }

    public void end() {
        if (getParent() != null)
            remove();
    }
}
```

For background of your gamePlay or you can say screen crate Image Object by passing texture of your required background and add to your stage. Background Image need to be add first before adding any other Actor to your stage.

Comment: thank you sir for your effort but there's an error in  this.setOrigin(origin.x, origin.y);     Error:(11, 36) error: package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.dump does not exist